# How to build a keras model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

As a complete beginner, I am having confusion in how to stack up keras layers and keras doc is not helping. I have a list of lists which contain float values, so the shape of my input is `(51,80,1)` where I have 51 lists in my final_list and each of those list contain 80 float values. I want to use this for prediction and I have labels in another list.

I have 3 output classes. I want to create a RNN model like this:

```
Layer               output_shape 
Input                (51,80,1)
GRU                  (51,100,1)
Dense                (51,100,1)
GRU                  (51,100)
LR                   (51,3)
```

So far I have done this :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(51,input_shape=(win_size,1)))
model.add(GRU(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
```

Can someone please help in learning this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target network design doesn't seem to start with the dense layer, but with GRU, so I removed it. The result code mimics the spec:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=100, input_shape=[80, 1]))
model.add(Dense(units=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Reshape([100, 1]))
model.add(GRU(units=100))
model.add(Dense(units=3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Note that you don't need to hardcode `51` in the model, since it's your batch size and doesn't affect model architecture.

Comment: Where can learn this from? Any resources besides the official doc

Comment: This page contains a lot of tutorials on different topics - https://github.com/fchollet/keras-resources

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!